# Find the volume of a solid bounded by planes x=0, y=0, z=0 and 2x + 3y + z = 6

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

Given question: Find the volume of a solid bounded by planes x=0, y=0, z=0 and 2x + 3y + z = 6

My doubts: Apparently, this is a tetrahedron so we can find the volume by double integration and setting limits accordingly. But how do I know this is a tetrahedron ***without*** a visualisation tool? Is there any sort of trick to figure out these type of problems?

Comment: A tetrahedron is an extension of a triangle. So just like a triangle is just any shape with three straight-edged sides, a tetrahedron is any solid with four planes as its faces.

Comment: You are basically trying to find the volume under a plane until the horizontal axes. This is just like the area under a line on a 2D cartesian plane until the x-axis. So, yes, you are right, you can use double integration because you all that's changed is the addition of an extra dimension.

Comment: You could use a triple integral, w.r.t to all variables: $$\int{\int{\int{dx}dy}dz}$$. Or to make it simpler: collect 2 variables in terms of the other and integrate with respect to those 2 (Basically integrating parallel to the variable (axis) chosen): $$z = 6 - 3y - 2x$$ $$\int{\int{dx}dy}$$ - along $z$, w.r.t $x, y$

Comment: When you say "figure out these type of problems", do you mean 1. Setting up and evaluating a double integral? 2. Figuring out the shape of a region bounded by equations? Or 3. Figuring out volumes in problems similar to this?

Comment: @MarkS. figuring out the shape of a region bounded by the equations

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion so it doesnt matter if i cant visualise in 3d, i just have to integrate as i usually do? 
the ans is 6 units right?

Comment: Yes it is $6$ units. *it doesnt matter if i cant visualise in 3d* - this is questionable. Do it if you can, because it is going to be helpful in figuring how the volume looks and might help with the bounds of the integration. However, don't waste the time if you cannot, there are other methods that can help - like drawing out the plane (not time effcient though). Overall, its not a necessity in figuring out the integrals. Given enough practice, you don't need to visualize to evaluate the integrals

Comment: @UnexpectedConfusion alrightt thank you